# Sending folders from the raspberry pi to another computer once they are created

Tags: automation, raspberry-pi, raspbian, data-transfer

I am currently capturing images when a GPIO pin is triggered and saving them to the raspberry pi itself. I want to be able to send those files to a computer on the same network automatically without having to ssh in using PUTTY, Filezilla, etc...

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at cron.

man cron

Put an access to where you want your files on your computer, and create a script that checks if there's a new video every X minutes/hours and copies it if that's the case. Launch the script with cron every X minutes/hours.